# Can Macintosh HD partition be resized while a BOOTCAMP partition resides on the same physical volume?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, bootcamp, partition

I have a HFS-partiion, a bootcamp partition and 100GB free unpartitioned space "in between". How can I resize my Mac partition to use it? All resizing controls seem to be disabled, here's the screenshot:

[image: disk utility with partition selected]

Guess I need some more advanced tool than the built-in Disk Utility?

[image: diskutil list results]

This is under OSX 10.7.5. With Paragon NTFS driver installed, if this matters...

Comment: Does `diskutil list` show two or three partitions larger than a GB? You might be stuck backing up and restoring BOOTCAMP if the resize is more important than that partition.

Comment: Don't you need to select a partition to be able to resize it

Comment: I did select it, of course. Still nothing: http://d.pr/i/hA5F

Comment: @bmike `diskutil list` shows this: http://d.pr/i/JAIe

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of this dialog when the middle partition is selected?

Comment: @Rabskatran I did, added it to the question

Answer (score 2):

Disk Utility won't touch things once you have a BOOTCAMP partition.

Look for third party utilities like [CampTune](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/camptune/) for on the fly adjustments (or at least ones after a reboot in some cases). You'll discover the same company Paragon that made the NTFS drivers, also makes CampTune